# Why does a dataframe allow 2-dimensional selection without a comma?

Tags: r

My understanding is that you can select from a dataframe in two ways. If you use `[]` and not include a comma, then it is a list-style selection. It works that way since a dataframe is built on a list and you are really just pulling from top level components.

And, if you include a comma, then you are doing matrix style selection and you get this syntax `[rows, columns]`.

If that's true, then why can I select from a dataframe with an array?

```
df <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
df2 <- cbind(df, rep(NA, nrow(df)))
df2[is.na(df2)]
```

`is.na()` is a an array with `dim` attributes for 50 rows and 9 columns.

How does it know to select against every value instead of doing the typical selection amongst columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is.na(df2)` produces a logical matrix, with the same dimensions as the data.frame, `df2`.

Subsetting a data.frame by a matrix of the same dimensions is a standard operation.  See `?'[.data.frame'` for more information.